# Recover password mail dosen't send to user laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

the password recovery email in laravel is not sent to the user 
and this is my function in controller :

```
public function recover(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->only('email'), [
        'email' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors()->all());
    }

    $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject(Config::get('boilerplate.recovery_email_subject'));
    });

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
          //  return $this->response->noContent();
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data' => $response], 200);
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
        //    return $this->response->errorNotFound();
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'data' => $response], 200);

    }
}
```

and I configure my .env and mail.php 
I use laravel 5.6

Answer (score 1):

1. if you are using gmail address to sent mail. then you need to on less secure app.

   go to https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

   then allow by turning it on.

   and also use

```php
 php artisan config:clear
```

2. sometimes google blocks when you try to send email through some code. In that case you got a alert mail. click on that mail(Check Activity) and mark as yes (Do you recognize this activity?)
3. Or you can try

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

and also use

```php
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: can you please put `backtick escapes` around the piece of code so that it seems clear which thing to run

Comment: @ssi-anik added

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to locate the problem.

I would suggest to try to setup `MAIL_DRIVER=log` and check `laravel.log` after executing this function. If nothing is found in the log - then you're not trying to send it. Most common problem, in this case, is using queues, so, check the `QUEUE_CONNECTION`variable in .env, it should be equal to "sync" (or set up your driver, like Redis if required).

By using "log" driver you should see your message in the log. If it works fine with "log" and doesn't work with smtp then you should get an error about it. If an error is present - please post it. If not - say so as well.

P.S. please note that if you're using `php artisan serve`, all variables from `.env` are updates only after restarting the php server.